# wpf automated tests, current state

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests

I know the question comes up every now and then. But because it hasn't been considered for a long time, I would like to ask it again. What would you recommend to create and run automated tests of a WPF application? Recording would be good too, of course, but it is not mandatory. Can you recommend something?

Comment: Depends what your app does. I routinely build tests which run on viewmodels. Bdd is particularly suited to apps which do calculatiing or otherwise manipulate sets of data. Tdd is best suited to apps where the data is disparate or where you need to explore to arrive at a good solution. And you may find only partial coverage really has much value

Answer (score 1):

Besides the possible automation bots - or better: UI testing by code - I actually haven't been working on that lately. So, therefore, I would like to approach this from a slightly different angle: How to test a WPF application?

In general; your testing capabilities - well, actually the ease of it - depend on how the program is structured.

Some examples:

- Dependency Injection: works very well in combination with unit tests.
- The MVVM pattern (suited for WPF): works very well with Dependency Injection and Unit Tests - And allows to isolate UI tests.
- Separation of layers - quite obvious, but often forgotten

Of course there are also test concepts to take into account:

- Unit tests
- Integration test
- Consumer Contract tests
- UI tests
- End to end test.

My guess is, you're referring to a tool to do the UI testing, as I said, it has been a while, so I can't give you an answer there - but what I can give you: good test-ability depends on a well defined architecture.

Here's something on UWP; I am pretty sure there was something similar for WPF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/test-uwp-app-with-coded-ui-test?view=vs-2019

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Appium](http://appium.io/) and WinAppDriver. It's a platform to test Web apps, mobile apps and desktop apps using the same API.

I have used [Specflow](https://specflow.org) together with Appium to do UI testing in a recent project.

If you want to go for UI testing using recording (no coding required) there a multiple options. Haven't used any of them, but there is: Microfocus Silk, SmartBear TestComplete and many more.

Some of these tools also provide you with Test Case Management as well.